# How to deal with django Template Does Not exist error in production server?

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates

I have just deployed my app to heroku for the first time but when i try and browse i get a `TemplateDoesNotExist`
and whats bothering me it is fine when i do a `python manage.py runserver`. I have looked around and seen some similar problems, but these guys never explained how they fixed their problem.

```
Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/templates/public/homepage.html (File does not exist)

Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/f4l/live/views.py" in homepage
  156.  return render_to_response('public/homepage.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  145.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  138.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: public/homepage.html
```

in my settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')
SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT

#FIXTURE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,  '../fixtures'),)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../templates'),)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../static'), os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../media'), )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../sitestatic')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Any answers and suggestion of readings is welcome.

Comment: Has this worked in testing?  It looks to me like you've got two problems, one is that your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is pointing two levels above the project root and also that you're trying to fetch templates from a directory called templates inside the template root.

Comment: its working in development environment. How do you suggest i fix the two problems you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've followed the guidelines in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). Your static and template directories are unusual, as TimD pointed out. I prefer a structure similar to that recommended by DeployDjango.com ([found here](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html)), in which each app has directories for its own static and template files. Something like:

```
|--project_root
   |--apps
      |--my_app
         |--static
         |--templates
   |--manage.py
...
```

That way the `collectstatic` command will automagically find them, according to the docs:

```
Put your static files somewhere that staticfiles will find them.
By default, this means within static/ subdirectories of apps in your
INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Also check that you're correctly running `collectstatic` on Heroku by following [their brief guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) on static files.

Comment: alright...let me try this out, so tht i can accept the answer